# Why will a force applied perpendicular to the motion of a point mass not change the magnitude of its velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If you have a point mass moving with some velocity 'v' and then a force is applied perpendicular to 'v', physics/mathematics claims no change in the magnitude of 'v' , just a change in direction. But that doesn't make intuitive sense to me because wouldn't a force cause an instantaneous change in the point mass velocity perpendicular to 'v'?

Therefore, wouldn't there be instantaneous velocity vectors perpendicular to each other and a resultant vector with a greater magnitude than 'v'?

Comment: The force as it turns, decreases the original component of velocity  and increases the component the force is acting

Comment: But the force is perpendicular to the original velocity so how can it cause a decrease?

Comment: Yeah, velocity in the initial direction would not change.

Comment: thinking in terms of infinistesimal amount of time, for the force at zero and the force at the next instant dt, one increases the component of velocity in the direction of the force, and at time dt, the force has now changed to perfectly cancel out the same addition of force in the original direction

Comment: Ohh so do you mean that force is always perpendicular to direction of object?

Comment: Jensen Paull: So are you are saying that by the time any infinitesimal change in the increase of velocity in its original direction can happen, the force has changed direction to cancel that change?

Comment: after reading your question again, I think you may not understand what the concept is, is you apply a force perpendicular to the inital velocity and keep that same force, ofcourse it will change it magnitude. this is different to applying the force perpendicular to the velocity at all times, which is a requirement of circular motion

Comment: I think I just answered this question, but idk how to link it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the velocity vector of an object is *always* tangent to the path it takes by definition, changes in the magnitude of the vector involve acceleration components also tangent to the velocity vector and hence the path.

Corollary to this, acceleration components not tangent to the velocity vector do not affect the magnitude of the velocity vector, but its direction.

Mathematically if we trace an object along its path, and designate $\boldsymbol{\hat t}$ the tangent vector and $\boldsymbol{\hat n}$ the normal vector (perpendicular) then we can always decompose the velocity vector as

$$ \boldsymbol{v} = v\; \boldsymbol{\hat{t}} \tag{1} $$

where the scalar $v$ is the speed (velocity magnitude).

Not the change in velocity is acceleration and it always decomposes along the two directions as

$$ \boldsymbol{a} = \dot{v}\; \boldsymbol{\hat{t}} + \frac{v^2}{\rho} \;\boldsymbol{\hat{n}} \tag{2} $$

where $\dot{v}$ designates change in speed (linear acceleration) and $\rho$ is the *radius of curvature*. This radius is an indication of how the *direction* of velocity changes along the path. It is purely geometric quantity because it removes the dependency of speed (and hence time) from the change in direction.

The smaller the radius, the higher the arc of movement the more rapid the change in direction is. If the radius of curvature is infinite then the second term goes to zero and the body is moving is a straight line but changing speed.

Comment: Hi John - many thanks and it does make sense the way you have answered my question. I  think I may have an incorrect perception of F=ma in its non-vector form .  When a net force is applied to a point mass, I have always equated this to an acceleration and therefore a rate of change in the magnitude of its velocity.

Comment: @Dubious - yes, I forgot to mention this fact, but since mass is scalar, the acceleration vector is always parallel to the force vector.